# WordPress Get all the Category's Post

Tags: wordpress

I have Developed WordPress Site Successfully, but i have doubt in Getting all the post by 
Categories.
 My Code is like this

```
new WP_Query("cat=54,71,72&order=ASC");
```

Default it is getting the first category id and the Post.

Thanks

Comment: This code is fine. It gets posts from all four categories.

Comment: but it is getting only the first category details not other

Comment: It works fine. Are you sure you have published posts in 71,72? Maybe increase number parameter from default 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get ALL your categories instead of a selected few, you don't need to query by category.

```
new WP_Query("order=ASC");
```

If you want to query a particular category, but you're not sure what's the category ID number, query it by category slug

```
new WP_Query("category_name=your-category-slug&order=ASC");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this code as well, just need to change the number of post, like as of now, below listed code is use for display 5 post only, so you have to change this limit.

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?>
<ul>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```